# find duplicate row after grouping based on two columns pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to group based on col1 and col2 and find duplicate row based on col2 between groups.

input

```
 col1            col2         col3
    A               0            2.0
    A               0            1.0
    A               0            3.0
    A               1            3.0
    A               1            4.0
    A               3            9.0
    B               0            3.0
    B               1            1.0
    B               1            1.0
    B               2            3.0
    C               2            4.0
    C               3            5.0
    C               1            6.0
    C               1            2.0
    C               4            3.0
```

Expected output :

```
0 in A , B
1 in A , B , C
2 in B , C
3 in A , C
4 in C
```

Comment: What is the expected output? A `DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `GroupBy.unique`, and join the strings after:

```
df.groupby('col2')['col1'].unique().str.join(', ')

col2
0       A, B
1    A, B, C
2       B, C
3       A, C
4          C
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

---

```
(df.groupby('col2')['col1']
   .unique()
   .str.join(', ')
   .to_frame()
   .apply(lambda x: f'{x.name} in {x[0]}', axis=1))

col2
0       0 in A, B
1    1 in A, B, C
2       2 in B, C
3       3 in A, C
4          4 in C
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows:

```
aggregated=df.groupby(['col2']).agg({'col1': 'unique'})
```

The output looks like:

```
col2           
0        [A, B]
1     [A, B, C]
2        [B, C]
3        [A, C]
4           [C]
```

And if you want to format it as in your example, you can execute:

```
aggregated.reset_index().apply('{0.col2} in {0.col1}'.format, axis='columns')
```

So it looks like this:

```
0        0 in ['A' 'B']
1    1 in ['A' 'B' 'C']
2        2 in ['B' 'C']
3        3 in ['A' 'C']
4            4 in ['C']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = df.groupby("col2").agg({"col1":"sum"}).reset_index(level=0)

d['col1'] = d['col1'].apply(set).str.join(',')
print(d)
```